# PHP MYSQL : mysqli_free_result

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

this is my first question in stackoverflow, hope you help me :)

So this is my problem:

```
function find_employer_by_email($email){
  global $connection;
  $q="SELECT * FROM employers WHERE email='{$email}' ";
  $res=mysqli_query($connection, $q);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) {
    return $employer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
  }
}
```

since my function is not returning the the query itself instead it returns the assoc array, what should i do to free result(mysqli_free_result) without messing my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're assigning the result of `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to `$employer`, why not just make that part of the function look like

```
$employer = null;
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $employer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$res->close();
return $employer;
```

That way, you'll always free your result, return the right object, and explicitly return null if no results are found.